# Unable to locate element - selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a program that will make proton e-mails by itself. Everything went smoothly until I had to create code that enters username and password. The problem is: It enters password but idk why it doesn't do the same thing with username. I tried putting every id I could find and it still didn't work.(I also tried to do something with classes or names but I failed).

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://protonmail.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Puhar\Desktop\chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href="signup"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("panel-heading").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id("freePlan").click()
time.sleep(6)
driver.find_element_by_id("domain").send_keys("juzername")
time.sleep(1.5)
driver.find_element_by_id("passwordc").send_keys("usernameForUser")
time.sleep(3.5)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys('usernameForUser')
time.sleep(1.5)
```

and here's error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\Puhar\Desktop\mejlhekler\mejlhekler1.py", line 20, in
>
> driver.find_element_by_id("domain").send_keys("juzername")
>
> File "C:\Users\Puhar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-
> packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
>
> return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: you're using sleeps, you should be using explicit waits. That could be why element is not being found, it hasn't loaded into the DOM yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong id tag. You were selecting the @protonmail.com dropdown instead of the input tag.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("juzername")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log `driver.find_element_by_id("domain").send_keys("juzername")`, we can know roughly where the error occurred.

See the below source page screenshot, we could get the correct code.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("juzername")
```

[image]

By the way, `//*[@href="signup"]`,`"panel-heading"` are not good idea to locate element you need, because each of them will find many elements. I think learning more xpath or cssSelector will help you.